# Keep an average of x numbers while still adding

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to keep a rolling average going. I need to say have 10 numbers in an array (or something else?) and keep adding to this and get the average of those numbers.

I have a program which each second will get a number and add this to a list. I then need the average of the last x numbers in that list. Also needs to limit the amount in the list so that memory doesnt fill up as it will be adding numbers each second.

Anyone can help? I have no idea where to start

eg array 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 average = 5.5

add next number 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 average = 6.5

and so on,

the array needs to be only the last 10 numbers added to the array

Comment: `array.Reverse().Take(10).Average()`

Comment: Is this, by any chance, a homework assignment?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The implementation of `Reverse` copies out the whole input sequence even if it's a collection.

Comment: @Rawling: thanks for the note. Why is that so? It could check if the collection already implements `IList<T>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not sure. `Reverse` uses `Buffer`, `Buffer` copies out the whole sequence. Maybe they insist on copying `IList`s too for consistency if the underlying collection changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a linked list for this. This makes list management easy and "low-cost". Resizing most other types of container is likely to require shuffling of data in memory. Removal from front is where LinkedList excels.

```
//make a linked list and fill it...
LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0,10));

list.AddLast(0);
while(list.Count > 10)
{
    list.RemoveFirst();
}
var avg = list.Average();
```

Comment: Calculating the average is relatively expensive. OP should keep a sum variable. Then add new value, subtract the value at RemoveFirst() and calc average as sum/count

Comment: @DrKoch Over 10 values? I wouldn't bother delving any deeper unless this was a performance hotspot...

Comment: Of course, with 10 values it's a toy example. But I find this interesting: in principle, a rolling average can be an O(1) operation as opposed to O(N) with .Average() (see answer of dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 4):

If you need an average of the last `x` numbers, make an array of `x` values, and use it as a [*circular buffer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Keep the running total in addition to the buffer. When a new number comes in, see if your circular buffer is filled. If it is, subtract the last number from the running total before adding the newly received number.

This will let you compute the new average in O(1) time instead of O(x), i.e. the computation time will be independent of the number of items being averaged.

Comment: @spender Linked list would be a better choice when `x` is not known upfront. When you know `x`, however, a plain array gets you as close "to the metal" as it gets in .NET, because you get virtually no overhead - in terms of memory use, cache performance, CPU instruction count, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generic list for this. Make sure you check if it actually holds at least 10 elements when you want to calculate the last 10 elements' average.

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(5);
//....
var average = list.Skip(list.Count - 10).Average();
```

Comment: I think your `Skip` is actually more performant - C# knows `Skip` can just jump to the correct item as it's working on a List, but `Reverse` still has to copy the whole list before it can take just 10 of its items.

Comment: @Rawling: [`Skip`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,83ec6a20321060a1,references) dose not jump to the correct item, it's also enumerating the whole sequence until the desired is reached. But you're right, it's more efficient in terms of memory consumption since it doesn't need to copy the whole thing into a new collection like `Enumerable.Reverse` does.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yup, I thought `Skip` would optimise for `IList`. Looks like we both expect more of LINQ-to-Objects than we actually get!

Comment: @OP: Actually you don't need to ensure that it contains at least 10 elements. If you pass a negative value or 0 to `Enumerable.Skip`  the whole sequence is returned. So your implementation is already safe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter However, if the argument to Skip is greater than the amount of elements in list, an empty IEnumerable<int> is returned: calling Average() on that throws an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @EmilePels: yes, but since `list.Count - 10` is never >= `list.Count` your code is safe. My point was that your suggestion _"Make sure you check if it actually holds at least 10 element"_ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays look like those in your example, you can simply observe that each time you add a new number to one end of the array and remove one from the other end, the average goes up by 1.  So you don't need the array at all--you just need to add 5.5 to `i`.

for `i = 0`:

```
(10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1) / 10 = 5.5 = 5.5 + i
```

for `i = 1`:

```
(11 + 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2) / 10 = 6.5 = 5.5 + i
```

for `i = 2`:

```
(12 + 11 + 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3) / 10 = 7.5 = 5.5 + i
```

... (you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

you could easily do this with a list instead of an array

just put a if check for the list being larger than you want and just have it remove the first item from the list.

```
List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();
if (Numbers.Count > 10)
{
    Numbers.RemoveRange(0, 0);
}
Numbers.Add(11);
var NewAverage = Numbers.Average();
```